# OnItemClickListener and setChecked in ListView in API 9 vs 17

Tags: android, listview, android-relativelayout

I have made a custom `RelativeLayout` that implements `checkable` for a `ListView`. I'm experiencing an error that occurs only on my Gingerbread running HTC Desire and NOT my JellyBean running Galaxy Nexus.

Within the custom `RelativeLayout`, I override the `setChecked` method as follows:

```
public class CustomRL extends RelativeLayout implements Checkable {

private boolean isChecked;
List<RelativeLayout> rl = new ArrayList<RelativeLayout>();
Context context;

public CustomRL(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
super(context, attrs);
this.context = context;
}

@Override
public boolean isChecked() {
return isChecked;
}

@Override
public void setChecked(boolean isChecked) {
this.isChecked = isChecked;
    this.setBackgroundColor(isChecked ? Color.parseColor("#33b5e5")
            : 0x00000000);
}
}
```

Within my onItemClickListener, I see if the item `isChecked` via the method above, casting the view as `customRL` as follows:

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listview, View v, int position,
            long id) {

        boolean isChecked = ((CustomRL) v).isChecked();
}
```

On my Galaxy Nexus, upon clicking of the item, `setChecked` runs before `isChecked` thus the latter returns whether the item has been checked correctly. On my Desire however, `isChecked` runs before `setChecked`, thus it returns the wrong value. This is reflected by the blue selected colour being set correctly on my Nexus and incorrectly on my Desire (when it is checked it isn't blue, and when it isn't checked it is blue)

This is really annoying and I've been wracking my brain for ages trying to work out why there is a difference. Anyone that can help?

Answer (score 0):

It may be late, but today I also encountered this same issue, for me even HTC One V (which was running ICS) was showing that same behavior, Gingerbread and Froyo devices were having the same issue that you mentioned. I fixed it by using a `Handler` inside the `onItemClick`.

Pseudo code:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listview, final View v, final int position, long id) {

    new Handler().post(new Runnable () { 
        // Your code here
        boolean isChecked = ((CustomRL) v).isChecked();
    } );
}
```